# How can I re-fetch an API automaticaly until data is fetched succesfully?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have an API that sometimes doesn't work. I would like for the App to refetch automaticaly if this happens until it gets the necessary data. How can I do that? I'm thinking that maybe this could be done by using a dependency on the `useEffect` hook, but I'm not clear on how to do it.

**Lets say we have this App component**

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getData({ setData })
  }, [])

   return [
    <h3>
      {data[0].title}
    </h3>
  ]
}
```

**And this API component**

```
const url = 'https://some-random-url.com/whatever-api'

export default function getData({ setData }) {

  axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      let dataArray = response.data.results
      setData(dataArray)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: A quick answer would be just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry then add `if (!data) return null`, though, I would very much recommend using a hook style approach like `useSWR` https://swr.vercel.app

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Thanks for the info! I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to do it with `useEffect`, you could pass an error counter state to `getData` function and increase it on error or empty data.
Then add to your `useEffect` dependency array to refetch.
But this certainly implies that you have to think further what you are wanting to do after a certain amount of retries, to avoid an infinite loop.

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [errCount, setErrCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    getData({ setData, errCount, setErrCount })
  }, [errCount])

   return [
    <h3>
      {data[0].title}
    </h3>
  ]
}
```

And this API component

```
const url = 'https://some-random-url.com/whatever-api'

export default function getData({ setData, errCount, setErrCount }) {

  axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      let dataArray = response.data.results
      setData(dataArray)
      !dataArray.length && setErrCount(errCount+1); 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setErrCount(errCount+1); 
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. One question, if the dataArray is empty what is `!dataArray.length` returning?

Comment: if its empty `!dataArray.length` returns true, so you increase the counter